# Identifying if a group of geospatial points is contained within another group

Tags: python, geospatial

At this stage in a project, I have two types of satellite data (MODIS and AMSR-E) already filtered and geospatially clustered. My next step is to identify if any of the clusters from the AMSR-E data lie within the bounds of any MODIS clusters.

I've clustered the high valued points from both datasets individually using the DBSCAN library from SciKit-learn in python - but I'm unsure how to identify if clusters of one type lie within clusters of the other.

My input from each dataset is stored in a python dictionary mapping the cluster ID to a list of points and their values. Said another way, the dictionaries look like this (though naturally with numbers in place of the variable names).

{ group_id: [(lat, long, data_val), (lat, long, data_val)] }

Any help in finding an algorithm to efficiently identify if clusters are contained inside of one another would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you give an example of what it would mean for one cluster to lie within the bounds of another cluster?  It's not clear to me.

Comment: I've only visually considered this so far, but imagine a cluster of a few hundred points is centered at 0 degrees longitude and latitude, and if you were to draw lines between the outermost points it would resemble a circle. Another cluster would lie inside of the first if when drawing lines between its edge points, the entire second shape was inside of the bounds of the first circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, you'll need two basic algorithms (of which there are many implementations)

[Point-in-polygon algorithm:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)
An algorithm to determine if a point is contained within a polygon given by a set of points.

[Convex-hull algorithm:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms)
An algorithm to determine, roughly speaking, given a set of points, the smallest polygon that completely encloses the points.

Here are two ideas for how to uses those algorithms to accomplish your goal:

1. Find the convex hull of each MODIS cluster.
2. Identify which AMSR-E clusters could potentially be inside which clusters of MODIS points by picking a random test AMSR-E point from each cluster, and using a point-in-polygon algorithm on all the computed MODIS convex hulls.
3. For each AMSR cluster that may potentially be in a MODIS convex hull, use a point-in-polygon algorithm on each of the AMSR-E points to determine if all of the AMSR-E points in that cluster are in the identified MODIS convex hull.

Since the convex hull algorithms and the point-in-polygon algorithms require different amounts of computation, depending on how many points there are in each cluster, this process may be more efficient:

1. Find the convex hull of each MODIS cluster.
2. Find the convex hull of each AMSR-E cluster.
3. Identify which AMSR-E clusters could potentially be inside which clusters of MODIS points by picking a random point from each AMSR-E convex hull, and using a point-in-polygon algorithm on all the computed MODIS convex hulls.
4. For each AMSR cluster that may potentially be in a MODIS convex hull, use a point-in-polygon algorithm on each of the points in the AMSR-E convex hull to determine if all of the AMSR-E convex hull points in that cluster are in the identified MODIS convex hull.